# Is there a wat to return the number of bars ago of a value

Tags: pine-script

I was wondering if there was a way to return the bars ago of lets say the lowest price within my lookback period.

something like

lowestVal = lowest(close, 90)

lowestValLen = length(lowestVal) // The bars ago from the current bar.

Answer (score 0):

the command i guess is lowestbars

```
lowestbars(90)
```

close is not declared, but i think is implied

More info https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_lowestbars